# Error in Visual-Studio "No module named 'IPython'"

Tags: python, visual-studio, module, ipython, vscode-debugger

When I run the script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
```

But the following error is displayed.
[image: Displayed Error]

I installed Ipython in the terminal. The version I have is 7.22

[image: Version of Ipython Installed]

Is it related to the interpreters?, These are my options available to select interpreters
[image: Interpreters]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have IPython installed in your base environment, are you sure you selected this as your interpreter in your code editor? In VSCode, you can change this by clicking on 'Python {version}' at the bottom left of your window.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just did what you suggested, but I can not find Ipython as an "interpreter." I update my question to show the interpreters available in my VStudio

Comment: Click the "base" environment, since that one has the IPython package installed. I'm not sure if this is the source of the issue but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the base environment in the "below right corner"? (I added the picture of my screen in the question). On this corner, it says "('base': conda)." As you can see, on this menu it do not show neither the Ipython option.

Comment: An envinronment is not a package. You can see it like an isolated playground or box where a specific version of Python is installed, and you can install all kinds of modules like IPython. People usually have an environment for every one of their projects, so the modules (or their versions) of different projects don't clash with each other. 
It seems that in your command prompt, while the (base) envinronment is activated, it can find your IPython module. However, with the same environment activated in VSCode, your code doesn't seem to find the module. I'm not sure how this is caused...